# Rosetta projects stop working after installing Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15, rosetta

I am currently working on a project using Xcode 14.1 with Rosetta implemented in it (I know it is not ideal but it is an old project). The thing is that since a few months ago in my department we are having the problem that every time we install Xcode 15, the projects that are in Xcode 14 or lower that use Rosetta stop working and the following message comes out.

[image: Error Rosseta]

The only solution we found was to reset the computer and never install Xcode 15 again, but due to technical issues, we have to upgrade to this version of Xcode and we have the same problem again.

Does anyone know of a solution that does not involve resetting the computer?

Comment: Perhaps run macOS with Xcode 14 on a [virtual machine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_macos_in_a_virtual_machine_on_apple_silicon)?

Comment: libs for simulator and iOS device is different, you should know the arc of the lib you use.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your error message, I think your framework does not have arm64 simulator architecture. To resolve this, you can exclude arm64 architecture to your project build process. For references, you can see more at [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon).

[Exclude arm64 simulator architecture in your build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVMgG.png)

In case you are using xcconfig, you can add following line to your xcconfig.

```
EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64
```